# How to search JSON Record in PHP?

Tags: php, json

This record is stored in a table field name 'description':

```
a:8:{
s:12:"cfdb7_status";s:4:"read";
s:9:"your-name";s:12:"Satyam Sagar";
s:10:"your-email";s:27:"sagarsatyam.15feb@gmail.com";
s:12:"your-contact";s:10:"9760960060";
s:10:"your-state";s:21:"38&#047;Uttar Pradesh";
s:9:"your-city";s:4:"Agra";
s:13:"your-locality";s:11:"Kamla Nagar";
s:11:"your-remark";s:10:"I want SAP";
}
```

I want to search this record behalf on key-name. I can't do this.

```
mysqli_query($connection, "select * from tbl_name where field_name->'$.your-name' = "satyam sagar"");
```

Comment: a JSON is basically a string, so if you need to search something it you will have to use functions for searching in string.

Comment: What did you want to search on? In the example?

Comment: Look at `json_decode` and `json_encode`.  There are methods that exist in PHP to process json, much simpler than using strings functions.  See https://www.w3schools.com/pHP/php_json.asp

Comment: There is absolutely no json in this question , why the title and tag ?

Comment: Looks more like a serialised PHP array. Definitely not JSON. Use [`unserialize()`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.unserialize.php) to convert it back to an array